# DataGrid-- one column uses different data from the others

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a `DataGrid` I'm binding to a `DataTable`, and displaying three `BoundColumn`s as a result.

I would like to have a fourth column that connects with different data-- for instance, if column #3 in the DataGrid is a UserID, I would like to use that to query against a database and retrieve the user's first name, and display it in the fourth column.

Are there any recommended approaches to this?  I'm not a DataGrid expert but should I be looking at a `TemplateColumn` or something along those lines?

Which event should I hook all this querying to, `OnItemDataBound`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is return the user's first name as part of the original query and just use a `BoundColumn`. If you need to modify data before displaying,  then yes you can use a `TemplateColumn` and the `OnItemDataBound` event to manipulate your data.

Running queries `OnItemDataBound` is not something I would ever encourage. So if your grid will show 100 records at once, you want to run 100 extra queries per page load? This is something that if you implement, could possibly run within reason during testing. Once under load though, you'll see have hundreds of extra queries running isn't a good idea... it can just be solved by fixing the original query or maybe making a denormalized table depending on your DB structure and the complexity of your query.

When I ran into similar issue, I went the denormalized table route.

Comment: You're absolutely right about not wanting to run 100 extra queries.  However the problem is the original data is being converted from an Excel worksheet into the DataTable I mentioned above-- and I don't have the user's first name in that worksheet.  The good news is there won't be more than 100 entries in the worksheet for any given page (crossed their hearts, the business folks did.)

Comment: @larryq: In that case your best bet is to run a second query to grab all of the users.  Then add a column to the datatable (in code) and fill in the user's name for each row.  Once that is done, do the databind.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join in your sql statement to get the other value.